# Why is Docker buildx consuming all ephemeral storage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, buildx

In the AWS/EKS environment, we build Docker images that are about 5GB in size. A build is failing because it is using all 150GB of ephemeral storage:

```
14:42:59  unable to retrieve container logs for containerd://51da8f0270e5ed3529ec0ef5cf9e60cafc109ddb4e2baf334185efaf3494491d
14:42:59  jenkins-xxxxxxxxxxx Pod just failed (Reason: Evicted, Message: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container builder was using 126387512Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container jnlp was using 40Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. )
```

We moved our Docker build jobs to EKS almost a year ago and didn't have any issues. But it could be that changes/additions in the Dockerfile make it take longer or require more space.

Perhaps there is some Docker in Docker issue, but again, it fails to create and push an image about 5GB when it uses up 150GB before it completes. (or EKS decided the storage pressure was too so great it had to stop)

Building the image locally only used 10GB in /var/lib/docker.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:18.04 AS ngcos-ubuntu

LABEL stage=ngcos-ubuntu
LABEL description="Ubuntu 18:04 for AOSP."

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    TERM=xterm

# Install standard packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils ca-certificates openssl gpg gpg-agent dirmngr && \
    apt-get install -y wget curl zip unzip xz-utils make gawk && \
    echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections && \
    update-ca-certificates -f && \
    update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Setting up Jenkins User
RUN groupadd -g 500 jenkins \
    && useradd  -d /home/jenkins -u 500 -g 500 -m jenkins \
    && echo 'jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
    && echo "jenkins:jenkins" | chpasswd

COPY resources/scripts/ubuntu.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

FROM ngcos-ubuntu AS ngcos-python

LABEL stage=ngcos-python
LABEL description="Python 3.7.5"

# ensure local python is preferred over distribution python
ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    apt-get install -y python3.7 && \
    rm /usr/bin/python3 && \
    ln -s python3.7 /usr/bin/python3 && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    python3 -m pip install -U pip && \
    pip3 install lxml && \
    pip3 install gitpython && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -V

# http://bugs.python.org/issue19846
# > At the moment, setting "LANG=C" on a Linux system *fundamentally breaks Python 3*, and that's not OK.
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
# You will have to adjust this after building and checking which version the package manager
# is configured to install.
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.7.5

# Unable to get this working
RUN python3 -m pip install -U pip > ver.txt 2>&1
RUN export PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=$(grep "Successfully installed pip" ver.txt | awk '{ print $3 }');

    FROM ngcos-python AS ngcos-release-notes

LABEL image=ngcos-release-notes
LABEL description = "Docker for Release Notes generation"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git

RUN pip3 install requests && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# non-root user
ENV USER=jenkins
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}

USER ${USER}

FROM ngcos-ubuntu AS ngcos-base

LABEL image=ngcos-base
LABEL description="AOSP Base Environment"

# 18.04 requirements
# sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev-i386 libncurses5 x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip fontconfig

# Installing standard packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
                       zlib1g-dev libc6-dev-i386 lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc ca-certificates-java \
                       bc lsof python python3-pip python3-wheel python3-setuptools maven doxygen openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-11-jdk 
RUN echo "N" | apt install -y --no-install-recommends sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk
ENV ANDROID_NDK_ARCH=linux-x86_64
ENV ANDROID_R_NDK_VERSION=android-ndk-r21
ENV ANDROID_R_NDK_SHA256=b65ea2d5c5b68fb603626adcbcea6e4d12c68eb8a73e373bbb9d23c252fc647b
ENV ANDROID_S_NDK_VERSION=android-ndk-r23c
ENV ANDROID_S_NDK_SHA256=6ce94604b77d28113ecd588d425363624a5228d9662450c48d2e4053f8039242

WORKDIR $ANDROID_NDK_HOME

# Download NDK
RUN wget -nv -nc "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/${ANDROID_R_NDK_VERSION}-${ANDROID_NDK_ARCH}.zip" && \
    echo "${ANDROID_R_NDK_SHA256}  ${ANDROID_R_NDK_VERSION}-${ANDROID_NDK_ARCH}.zip" | sha256sum --check --strict - && \
    unzip -q -n "${ANDROID_R_NDK_VERSION}-${ANDROID_NDK_ARCH}.zip" && \
    echo "" > $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/${ANDROID_R_NDK_VERSION}/Android.mk

RUN wget -nv -nc "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/${ANDROID_S_NDK_VERSION}-linux.zip" && \
    echo "${ANDROID_S_NDK_SHA256}  ${ANDROID_S_NDK_VERSION}-linux.zip" | sha256sum --check --strict - && \
    unzip -q -n "${ANDROID_S_NDK_VERSION}-linux.zip" && \
    echo "" > $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/${ANDROID_S_NDK_VERSION}/Android.mk

RUN update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

# Install ADB
RUN wget -nv "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-linux.zip" && \
    echo '35390ae455cf0f9e8335364956a9c6bb8fa16670396105d8224550f8cf8bbb16  platform-tools_r28.0.0-linux.zip' | sha256sum --check --strict - && \
    rm -f /usr/bin/adb && \
    unzip -q -j "platform-tools_r28.0.0-linux.zip" "platform-tools/adb" -d "/usr/bin" && \
    rm -f platform-tools_r28.0.0-linux.zip

#AWS SDK For S3 https://github.com/boto/boto3
RUN pip3 install -U boto3 configparser requests jsonschema


#Disabling env preservation for sudoing command in "/entrypoint.sh"
RUN echo 'Defaults        !env_reset' >> /etc/sudoers
RUN echo 'Defaults        !secure_path' >> /etc/sudoers

ENV JENKINS_REMOTING_VERSION 3.27

WORKDIR /aosp
COPY starterScripts/baseStarter.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENV USER=jenkins
USER ${USER}
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

FROM ngcos-base AS ngcos-builder

LABEL image=ngcos-builder
LABEL description="AOSP Build Environment"

USER root

# Installing standard packages
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mtools libssl-dev dosfstools rsync bsdmainutils cpio && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Setting up AOSP mirror service User
RUN groupadd -g 1000 'svc.aosp' && \
    useradd --no-create-home -u 1000 -g 1000 'svc.aosp'

# Update jack settings for jenkins
ENV USER=jenkins
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}

RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /aosp

USER ${USER}

FROM ngcos-base AS ngcos-bist-builder

LABEL image=ngcos-bist-builder
LABEL description="BIST Build Environment"

# Installing standard packages
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y ninja-build file texinfo cpio repo libudev-dev \
    autoconf rsync openssh-client graphviz gettext systemtap-sdt-dev \
    binutils-dev libiberty-dev libssl-dev gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 gcc-mingw-w64-i686 \
 && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a non-root user
ENV USER=jenkins
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}

USER ${USER}

FROM ngcos-base AS ngcos-android-sdk

LABEL image=ngcos-android-sdk

ENV ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=4333796
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools

# Add a group for work with Android SDK
USER root
RUN groupadd sdkuser && \
    mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME && \
    chgrp sdkuser $ANDROID_HOME && \
    chmod g+s $ANDROID_HOME

WORKDIR $ANDROID_HOME

# Install Android SDK
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-$ANDROID_SDK_VERSION.zip -O sdk-tools-linux.zip && \
    unzip -q sdk-tools-linux.zip && \
    rm sdk-tools-linux.zip && \
    chmod -R g+w $ANDROID_HOME

# Download android build and platform tools and ndk
ENV ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}
RUN umask 002 && \
    sg sdkuser "yes | sdkmanager --licenses" && \
    sg sdkuser "sdkmanager 'build-tools;28.0.2'" && \
    sg sdkuser "sdkmanager platform-tools" && \
    sg sdkuser "sdkmanager ndk-bundle" && \
    find $ANDROID_HOME -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;

# Create a non-root user
ENV USER=user
ENV HOME=/home/${USER}
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --groups sdkuser ${USER} && \
    echo "${USER}:${USER}" | chpasswd && adduser ${USER} sudo
```

Comment: Well. What does your `Dockerfile` look like? Does it happen over time? Or does a new node instantly have this issue?

Comment: Ran it on a node with a terabyte... it works, but it uses 100+ GB to build a 5GB image, so strange.

Comment: Can you share output of `docker info` and the exact buildx command you’re using? Are you using the same version locally as in AWS?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, apologies for no reply in a while. My contract ended and I don't have access to the system. Thank you for your interest/ideas. The build was moved to a system with terabyte of ephemeral storage, so working, but not solved.